# Unwanted space at the right of the site

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position, css-tables

I've been building a site and I get a horizontal scrollbars and huge space to the right of the product pages. My first thought was an unclosed div, but I have validated with W3C and it checks out.
I wonder if it's because of something (the buttons,tabs) that is relatively positioned. Would you please point me in the right direction. Any help is much appreciated.

[Validation link with source](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcheapgamessales.com%2Fproduct%2FEets.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)

[Page link](http://cheapgamessales.com/product/Eets.html)

I'll post the image in the comment since I don't get enough reputation.

Comment: A [screencap](http://i1350.photobucket.com/albums/p769/Stonecold_Stone/problem3_zpsf06498ed.png) of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `width: 100%;` on `#cssmenu ul ul`

It's at **line 342** in **style.css?ver=3.6**

This is causing your little issue. Remove it if you can.

Comment: firebug for firefox - https://getfirebug.com/ Then its just a case of elimination (you can turn styles on/off and remove markup in the browser to see the effects)

Comment: @user35295 in case you're unaware, you can mark a correct answer by clicking the tick below the voting buttons on the left.

Answer (score 0):

give to your #wrap div `overflow-x: hidden`. because some unknown child div has a very big width.