# Padding to the right of my site

Tags: css

I've been looking everywhere as to why this is happening. I don't necessarily have code to showcase as I have no clue where it's coming from. It DOES however look like it may be coming from something within the CSS for the mobile styles from 768 and down...?

[This is the website I'm working on](http://onlinewebdraft.com/)

What's happening is I'm getting some padding (?) to the right of my site. It doesn't seem to show in firefox, but it does in chrome and then when I test it in mobile devices.

I've look at this question/answer ([Unwanted space at the right of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397547/unwanted-space-at-the-right-of-the-site)) and have looked through my styles but can't find another div that is setting itself to be wider than the screen.

Any suggestion or advice would be great! Thanks in advance!

[image]

UPDATE:

When you highlight the text and move to the far right, that's when the padding will show up in chrome.. At least it does that for me.

[image]

Comment: Is this happening on all browsers?

Comment: For me it works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox and Android Chrome. Do you have some weird browser extensions installed? I can see LastPass, are there more?

Comment: Hmm.. I dont have much. Just last pass. If you go to the bottom and then highlight the text and keep moving to the right the padding should show up. See added screenshot to revised question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is located in `margin-right: 4.5em;`. Try to remove it.

[image]

```
#angela-footer-contact .widget_black_studio_tinymce {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 4.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed it. :/